# Named range in formula not behaving

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have defined 2 name ranges, MonthClosed and EmailSent. Using the formula: `=COUNTIFS(MonthClosed),C2,EmailSent,"<>")`

`C2 = Jan-20`.

I've taken the formula across the row so that `D2=Feb-20` etc

The data is pulling through correctly for the months of Apr-20 & May-20 but nothing at all in Jan, Feb or March, even though there is data for these months within the named range. Any idea why?

Comment: Attach some screenshots so we better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question as I understand it.

I'm assuming this is because you are referencing to an absolute and unchanging range. You can check where the range refers to using [ctrl]+[F3]

If you want to refer to a different row every time perhaps use relative references without the names, or tilt your data and put it into a table. When you've got data in a table you can use a formula for an entire column, and refer to a cell in the same row like so: `[@[ColumnName]]`
If you want to refer to your entire column leave out `@`